# Varnish + nginx + ELB 499 responses

Tags: sockets, nginx, varnish, amazon-elb, varnish-4

I am having varnish 4 server working with nginx as reverse proxy connected to ELB.

Every 2 days or so my server is stop responding and I see 499 responses in nginx access.log

restarting nginx is solving the problem.

Why am I started to get these 499 responses?

Why restarting nginx solving the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my issue after understanding two facts:

1) ELB instance has dynamic DNS name

2) nginx resolve DNS names only on reload/restart

The problem was that the ELB changed its IP address and nginx kept the old IP address.

The solution is to use resolver in nginx.conf. Here is my nginx.conf:

```
http {  

    resolver x.x.x.x valid=30s;

}

server {

    set $elb "example.com";

    location / { 

        proxy_pass http://$elb; 

        }
}
```

The resolver IP address should be a DNS server such in /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: I don't understand this completely. What exactly are you doing in this configuration?

Comment: I set the elb address to a param and proxy_pass there. In addition, I set a resolver so this address will be up to date (with the right ip address) @AbhyuditJain

Comment: if the ip address is changing then how do i set the ip? you are hard coding ip?

Comment: You don't set an ip. You set an hostname.

Comment: @AbhyuditJain You should use the resolver param in the nginx.conf. Follow the instructions above above.

Comment: I seem to be getting a similar issue but i am not sure whether it is the same. If you don't restart the nginx after two days all responses are 499 or just a few responses are 499 ? In my case I have few 499 in my nginx access log. Just wanted to confirm whether it is the same issue.

Comment: `169.254.169.253`

Anyone looking for the AWS DNS address can use the above.
From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#AmazonDNS