# nginx and ELB 499 response

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb

I am using nginx as reverse proxy server under ELB.
Every two days I start to get 499 responses. When I restart nginx the problem is solved for the next two days.

A solution I saw for this problem is to change the idle timeout of the ELB but it does not explain why restartin nginx temporary solved my issue.

Comment: 499 means the client is closing the connection, and as you pointed out, it's probably the ELB's idle timeout. I'm guessing it's something to do with your keepalive config. When you restart nginx you're essentially dropping all active connections - it might be a good idea to see how many active connections you have going when you start seeing these errors.

Comment: @guyyug did you fix the issue?

Comment: @AbhyuditJain Yes. I added my solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200938/varnish-nginx-elb-499-responses/40357588#40357588

Answer (score 0):

Cejast is correct, 499 is a Client is closing the connection.

Reference:
https://httpstatuses.com/499